# jQuery line break won't be appended when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a plain textarea for a form submission.  I want to force a line break when ENTER is pressed.  Right now I can get it to recognize when ENTER e.g. keyCode 13 is pressed.  But, it won't append a line break to the outputted html.  How is this done and if so, how would the `<br /><br />` be hidden from the user.  Thank you

```
    <textarea cols="50" rows="7" id="textarea"></textarea>

    <p><div id="data"></div></p>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#textarea').bind('keyup', function(e) {

            data = $('#textarea').val()
            $('#data').html(data);

            if(e.keyCode==13){
                $('#data').append('<br/><br />'); // <--- This won't work
                }

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Textareas already do this by default, you just need to replace the new line characters with `<br />` tags when you display it as html.

Comment: did you try `\n` ? And set the wrap on the textarea?

Comment: it is working, but its getting knocked out by the next key press. you want to replace `\n` with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#textarea').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    var data = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#data').html(data.replace(/\n/g,"<br />"));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/efLxP/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're printing data inside `<p>` tags, use `<span>` instead of `<div>`. To solve your problem, try this:

```
$('#textarea').bind("keydown", function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));

    data = $('#textarea').val()

    $('#data').html(data);

    if (keycode == 13) {
         $('#data').html(data.replace(/\n/g,"<br />"));
         return false;
    }
});
```